# How to integrate matlab with hadoop

Tags: matlab, hadoop, image-processing, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

I am interested in distributed image processing. I have a Hadoop cluster of 32 nodes and I want to distribute images on nodes, process them, then collect the result from each of them (more like map-reduce).
Please explain all the possible ways of distributed image processing (like using matlab distributed server, using Hadoop cluster etc).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Matlab and how it can export data from it, but for Hadoop side I would recommend you to use Hadoop Storm service. You can organize a gateway for your images inside Kafka message broker. There you can push your images. In Storm you can create custom workflow for your images. You can perform some Computer Vision algorithms upon them for example, or just save them to HDFS or HBase or any other relevant storage. If you are able to export data from mathlab to Kafka, maybe by means of some standalone service, then Storm is definitely your way to go.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB has a [`mapreduce`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/mapreduce.html) function that you can use with a Hadoop cluster. This is described [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-mapreduce-on-a-hadoop-cluster.html) in the Parallel Computing Toolbox documentation - the page shows you a complete example of how to run `mapreduce` on a Hadoop cluster. You'll need a Parallel Computing Toolbox licence on your desktop client, and [MATLAB Distributed Computing Server](https://www.mathworks.com/products/distriben.html) licences for your Hadoop cluster.